# Kendo Grid Grouping on column - TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

i have problem with grouping data in the Kendo Grid.

I i drag the column which i want to use for group i always got following error.

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I tried to find where error is triggered but without luck.

Grouped data from server are returned back.

Many Thanks for any advice.

GRID INIT CODE:

```
$scope.initGrid = function() {

      console.log("init locations grid");
        // set container for loading spinner
        gridView = $("#locations_grid");
        // set all properties for data grid
        gridView.kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    // READ REQUEST
                    read: function (options) {
                        console.log("List");
                        console.log(options.data);
                        requestParams = {
                            "entityName": "Location"
                        };
                        requestParams.data = options.data;

                        console.log(requestParams);
                        ApiService.doHttpRequest(
                                "POST",
                                $rootScope.apiBaseUrl + "location/search",
                                requestParams
                        )
                        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            // successful data retrieval
                            console.log("request success, checking state");
                            console.log(data);
                            // sent status to global HTTP status service
                            var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
                            console.log("Status response is " + jsonResponse.result);
                            // do something with data
                            switch (jsonResponse.result) {
                                case true:
                                    options.success(data);
                                    break;
                                case false:
                                    growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('LIST_LOADING_ERROR'), 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                                    break;
                            }
                        })
                        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
                            console.log("Processing error with status " +status);
                            growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('PROCESSING_REQUEST_ERROR') + jsonResponse.message , 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                            // hide loading spinner
                            kendo.ui.progress(gridView, false);
                        });
                    },
                    // DELETE FUNCTION
                    destroy: function (options) {
                        console.log("delete");
                        console.log(options.data);
                        // add data to request params
                        console.log("delete id: " +options.data.id);
                        // call the service
                        ApiService.doHttpRequest(
                            "POST",
                            $rootScope.apiBaseUrl + "/location/delete",
                            requestParams)
                            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                // successful data retrieval
                                console.log("request success, checking state");
                                console.log(data);
                                // sent status to global HTTP status service
                                var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
                                console.log("Status response is " + jsonResponse.result);
                                // do something with data
                                switch (jsonResponse.result) {
                                    case true:
                                        options.success(data);
                                        break;
                                    case false:
                                        growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('LIST_LOADING_ERROR'), 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                                        break;
                                }
                            })
                            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
                                console.log("Processing error with status " +status);
                                growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('PROCESSING_REQUEST_ERROR') + jsonResponse.message , 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                                // hide loading spinner
                                kendo.ui.progress(gridView, false);
                            });
                    },
                    // CREATE FUNCTION
                    create: function (options) {
                        console.log("Create");
                        console.log(options.data);
                        // ADD DATA FOR UPDATE TO THE TOKEN
                        requestParams = options.data;
                        ApiService.doHttpRequest(
                            "POST",
                            $rootScope.apiBaseUrl + "location/create",
                            requestParams
                        )
                            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                // successful data retrieval
                                console.log("request success, checking state");
                                console.log(data);
                                // sent status to global HTTP status service
                                var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
                                console.log("Status response is " + jsonResponse.result);
                                // do something with data
                                switch (jsonResponse.result) {
                                    case true:
                                        options.success(data);
                                        var dataSource = gridView.dataSource;
                                        gridView.data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
                                        growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('SUCCESSFULLY_ADDED'), 'success',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                                        break;
                                    case false:
                                        growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('PROCESSING_ERROR'), 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                                        options.success(data);
                                        break;
                                }

                            })
                            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                var jsonResponse =  ApiService.processReturnedHttpState(status);
                                console.log("Processing error with status " +status);
                                growlNotifications.add($translate.instant('PROCESSING_REQUEST_ERROR') + jsonResponse.message , 'error',  $rootScope.notificationLifetime);
                                // hide loading spinner
                                kendo.ui.progress(gridView, false);
                            });
                    }
                },
                requestStart: function(e) {
                    console.log("Request start");


                },
                requestEnd: function(e) {
                  console.log("Request end");

                  // hide loading spinner
                  kendo.ui.progress(gridView, false);

                },
                requestError: function(e) {
                    console.log("Request error");
                    // hide loading spinner
                    kendo.ui.progress(gridView, false);
                },
                // SCHEMA FOR DATAGRID
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "id",
                        fields: {
                            id: {
                                editable: false,
                                nullable: true,
                                defaultValue: null,
                                type: "number"
                            },
                            accessNote: {
                                editable: false,
                                nullable: true,
                                type: "string"
                            },
                            address: {
                                editable: false,
                                defaultValue: {},
                                nullable: true
                            },
                            bsc: {
                                editable: false,
                                nullable: true
                            },
                            code:{
                                editable: false,
                                nullable: true,
                                type: "string",
                                validation: {
                                    required: true,
                                    min: 1
                                }
                            },
                            indoorOutdoor:{
                                editable: false,
                                nullable: true,
                                type: "string",
                                validation: {
                                    required: {
                                        message: $translate.instant('FIELD_IS_REQUIRED')
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            siteId:{
                                editable: false,
                                nullable: true,
                                type: "string",
                                validation: {
                                    required: {
                                        message: $translate.instant('FIELD_IS_REQUIRED')
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            shared: {
                              editable: false,
                              nullable: true,
                              type: "boolean"
                            },
                            partner: {
                              nullable: true,
                              editable: false,
                              defaultValue: {},
                            },
                            stationType:{
                                nullable: true,
                                editable: false,
                                defaultValue: {},

                            },
                            abloyLocation:{
                                editable: false,
                                type: "string",
                                defaultValue: ""
                            },
                            sapSacIrnCode:{
                              editable: false,
                              type: "string",
                              defaultValue: ""
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    data: function(response) {
                        console.log(response.results);
                        if (response.results.length == 0) {
                          return [];
                        }
                        return response.results;
                    },
                    total: function(response) {
                        console.log(response.resultCount);
                        return response.resultCount;
                    }
                },
                // definition for page sorting
                pageSize : GridHelperService.setDefaultPageSize(),
                serverPaging: true,
                serverFiltering: true,
                serverSorting: true,
                serverGrouping: true
            },
            editable:{
                confirmation:true //remove delete confirm message
            },
            scrollable:true,
            //window resizing hack
            height: function () {
               return GlobalHelperService.getWindowSize();
            },
            filterable: GridHelperService.filtersTranlations(),
            sortable: true,
            groupable : {
                messages: {
                    empty : $translate.instant('DRAG_SELECTED_COLUMN_HEADER_HERE_TO_GROUP')
                }
            },
            reorderable: true,
            resizable: true,
            //dataBound: resizeGrid, //callback when data are loaded
            columnMenu: GridHelperService.getColumnMenu(),
            pageable: GridHelperService.getBottomToolbar(),
            messages:GridHelperService.getToolbarButtonsTranlations(),
            toolbar: [
                { name: "create" },
                { template: kendo.template($("#template").html()) },
            ],
            columns: [
                {
                    field :"partner.name",
                    editable: false,
                    title : $translate.instant('PARTNER'),
                    width: 250,
                    template: function(data) {
                      console.log("Data are");
                      try {
                        if(data.partner.name === null) {
                          console.log("Partner is null");
                          return "";
                        } else {
                          return data.partner.name;
                        }
                      } catch (e){
                        return "";
                      }

                    },
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            operator: "contains"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    field :"accessNote",
                    title : $translate.instant('ACCESS_NOTE'),
                    width: 250,
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            operator: "contains"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                  field :"abloyLocation",
                  title : $translate.instant('ABBLOY_LOCATION'),
                  width: 250,
                  filterable: {
                    cell: {
                      operator: "contains"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                    field :"address.city",
                    title : $translate.instant('ADDRESS_CITY'),
                    width: 250,
                    template: function(data) {
                      console.log("Data are");
                      try {
                        if(data.address.city === null) {
                          console.log("Is null");
                          return "";
                        } else {
                          return data.address.city;
                        }
                      } catch (e){
                        return "";
                      }

                    },
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            operator: "contains"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    field :"address.latitude",
                    title : $translate.instant('ADDRESS_LAT'),
                    width: 250,
                    template: function(dataItem) {
                      console.log("ADDRESS_LON IS FOLLOWING:");
                      try {
                        console.log(dataItem.address.latitude);
                        if(dataItem.address.latitude === null) {
                          return "";
                        } else {
                          console.log("TRYING TO GET LENGTH");
                          var stringLon = dataItem.address.latitude.toString();
                          var lengthOfString = stringLon.toString().length;
                          console.log("LENGTH IS:");
                          console.log(lengthOfString);
                          if(lengthOfString >= 5) {
                            console.log("IS LONG");
                            var trimmedString = stringLon.substring(0, 5);
                            console.log("TRIMMED STRING");
                            console.log(trimmedString);
                            return trimmedString;
                          }
                          else {
                            console.log("IS SHORT");
                            return stringLon;
                          }
                        }
                      } catch (e){
                        console.log("EXC ADDRESS_LAT");
                        return "";
                      }

                    },
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            operator: "eq"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    field :"address.longitude",
                    title : $translate.instant('ADDRESS_LON'),
                    width: 250,
                    template: function(dataItem) {
                      try{
                        if(dataItem.address.longitude === null) {
                          return "";
                        } else {
                          console.log("TRYING TO GET LENGTH");
                          var stringLon = dataItem.address.longitude.toString();
                          var lengthOfString = stringLon.toString().length;
                          console.log("LENGTH IS:");
                          console.log(lengthOfString);
                          if(lengthOfString >= 5) {
                            console.log("IS LONG");
                            var trimmedString = stringLon.substring(0, 5);
                            console.log("TRIMMED STRING");
                            console.log(trimmedString);
                            var html = "<div>"+trimmedString+"<a class=\"showOnMapBtn\" href=\"http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+dataItem.address.latitude+","+dataItem.address.longitude+"&z=14&ll="+dataItem.address.latitude+","+dataItem.address.longitude+"\" target=\"blank\">"+$translate.instant('MAP')+"</a></div>";
                            return html;
                          }
                          else {
                            console.log("IS SHORT");
                            var html = "<div>"+stringLon+"<a class=\"showOnMapBtn\" href=\"http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+dataItem.address.latitude+","+dataItem.address.longitude+"&z=14&ll="+dataItem.address.latitude+","+dataItem.address.longitude+"\" target=\"blank\">"+$translate.instant('MAP')+"</a></div>";
                            return html;
                          }
                          console.log("ADDRESS_LON IS FOLLOWING:");
                          console.log(dataItem.address.longitude);
                        }
                      } catch(e) {
                        console.log("EXC ADDRESS_LON");
                        return "";
                      }
                        },
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            operator: "eq"
                        }
                    }

                },
                {
                    field :"address.street",
                    title : $translate.instant('ADDRESS_STREET'),
                    width: 250,
                    editor: GlobalHelperService.getAddressStreetListForAutocomplete,
                    template: function(dataItem) {
                      try{
                        if(dataItem.address.street === null) {
                          return "";
                        } else {
                          return dataItem.address.street;
                        }
                      } catch(e) {
                        return "";
                      }
                    },
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            operator: "contains"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                  field :"address.district",
                  title : $translate.instant('ADDRESS_DISTRICT'),
                  template: function(dataItem) {
                    try{
                      if(dataItem.address.district === null) {
                        return "";
                      } else {
                        return dataItem.address.district;
                      }
                    } catch(e) {
                      return "";
                    }
                  },
                  width: 250,
                  filterable: {
                    cell: {
                      operator: "contains"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  field :"address.streetNumber",
                  title : $translate.instant('ADDRESS_STREET_NUMBER'),
                  template: function(dataItem) {
                    try{
                      if(dataItem.address.streetNumber === null) {
                        return "";
                      } else {
                        return dataItem.address.streetNumber;
                      }
                    } catch(e) {
                      return "";
                    }
                  },
                  width: 250,
                  filterable: {
                    cell: {
                      operator: "contains"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                    field :"bsc",
                    title : $translate.instant('BSC'),
                    width: 250,
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            operator: "contains"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    field :"code",
                    title : $translate.instant('CODE'),
                    width: 250,
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            operator: "contains"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    field :"indoorOutdoor",
                    title : $translate.instant('INDOOR_OUTDOOR'),
                    editor: GlobalHelperService.locationTypeDropDownEditor,
                    template: function(dataItem) {
                        switch (dataItem.indoorOutdoor)
                        {
                            case "Indoor":
                                return "Indoor";
                            case "Outdoor":
                                return "Outdoor";
                            case "IndoorOutdoor":
                                return "Indoor & Outdoor";
                            default:
                                return "Neuvedeno";
                        }
                    },
                    width: 250,
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            operator: "contains"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    field :"siteId",
                    title : $translate.instant('SITE_ID'),
                    width: 250,
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            operator: "contains"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                  field :"sapSacIrnCode",
                  title : $translate.instant('SAPSACIRNCODE'),
                  width: 250,
                  filterable: {
                    cell: {
                      operator: "contains"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                    field :"stationType.name",
                    title : $translate.instant('STATION_TYPE'),
                    editor: GlobalHelperService.getStationTypeListForAutocomplete,
                    template: function(data) {
                     try{
                        console.log("Data are");
                        console.log(data.stationType.name);
                        if (data.stationType.name === null) {
                          return "";
                        } else {
                          return data.stationType.name;
                        }
                      }
                      catch(e) {
                        return "";
                      }
                    },
                    width: 250,
                    filterable: {
                        cell: {
                            operator: "contains"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                  command:
                    [
                      {
                        name: "detail",
                        click: function(e) {
                          var clickedRow = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
                          var workerId = clickedRow.id;
                          GlobalHelperService.redirectTo("/locations/detail/"+workerId);
                          return false;
                        }
                      }
                    ],

                  title: $translate.instant('ACTIONS'),
                  width: 90,
                  filterable: {
                    cell: {
                      operator: "contains"
                    }
                  },
                  locked: true,
                  lockable: true
                }
            ]
        });

        // HACK FOR ADD NEW RECORD BUTTON CLICK HANDLED BY ANGULAR JS
        $('.k-header').on('click', '.k-grid-add', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          GlobalHelperService.redirectTo("/locations/create");
          return false;
        });
    };
```

Comment: You should share some more information about your question. Sample code or JSFiddle would help us understand what is your problem.

Comment: I just added the code of the grid.

Comment: And here is complete error message:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at v (kendo.all.min.js:10)
    at _ (kendo.all.min.js:10)
    at s [as groups] (kendo.all.min.js:10)
    at ht.extend._readData (kendo.all.min.js:11)
    at ht.extend.success (kendo.all.min.js:11)
    at Object.ht.extend.read.n._queueRequest.n.trigger.n.online.n.transport.read.success (kendo.all.min.js:11)
    at locations.js:189
    at angular.js:7733
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11100)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11100)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting exceptions because of conflicts and problems mentioned on Kendo Forum [Here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-web-min-js-and-kendo-dataviz-min-js-conflicts-in-pageable-grid) and [Here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/updated-to-2014-3-1119-several-js-errors-in-grid)

Please avoid using

```
kendo.web.min.js
kendo.dataviz.min.js
```

using both of them and using kendo.all.min.js will return such exceptions when performing read operation for Kendo DataSoruce because kendo.web.min.js and kendo.dataviz.min.js share common code (kendo.core.js, kendo.data.js etc) and using them will create conflicts and will return exceptions For DataSource when returning success at read function.

```
Object.n.trigger.n.online.n.transport.read.success
Object.ht.extend.read.n._queueRequest.n.trigger.n.online.n.transport.read.success
```